# populate datatable with json array when some columns are empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatables, populate

I am trying to populate datatable from js. Currently I am able to do that, but my current data has blank columns in some last rows, hence that columns are populated first. I tried filling those blank columns, then data is populated in order. 
My sample data is :

```
var dataSet =  { "SlNo": 1, "InvTransactionMasterID": 4, "VType": 'SI', "Form": null, "VNo": 333, "Prefix": null, "Date": null, "Ledger": "Total CashSale", "TotalGross": 23444.00, "BillDiscount": null, "GrandTotal": null, "Product": null, "Qty": null, "Rate": null, "Rent": null, "CashReceived": null, "Area": null, "Employee": null, "Remarks": null, "VehicleName": null, "VehicleNam": null, "Time": null }, 
{ "SlNo": null, "InvTransactionMasterID": null, "VType": null, "Form": null, "VNo": null, "Prefix": null, "Date": null, "Ledger": "Total CreditSale", "TotalGross": 0, "BillDiscount": null, "GrandTotal": null, "Product": null, "Qty": null, "Rate": null, "Rent": null, "CashReceived": null, "Area": null, "Employee": null, "Remarks": null, "VehicleName": null, "VehicleNam": null, "Time": null }];
```

Current Output screenshot:

[image]

It shows the first row in last place and second row in first. When I give a value for "SlNo" column instead of null, output is accurate.

JS code to populate :

```
$('#example').DataTable({                
            data: dataSet,
            columns:
            [
                    {
                        "data": "SlNo",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "InvTransactionMasterID",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "VType",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Sl",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Form",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "VNo",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Prefix",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Date",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Ledger",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "TotalGross",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "BillDiscount",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "GrandTotal",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Product",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Qty",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Rent",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Rate",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "CashReceived",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Area",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Employee",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Remarks",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "VehicleName",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "VehicleNam",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Time",
                        "defaultContent": ""
                    }
            ]
        });
```

How to populate in correct order? There will null values for "SlNo" column in some rows, hence its not possible to fill that column.

Answer (score 0):

You Just need to add an ID column and use this `DataTable` option `orderFixed: [ID_column_number, 'asc']`, Here is an example:

https://datatables.net/reference/option/orderFixed

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
    "orderFixed": [ 0, 'asc' ]
} );
```

Comment: I think id column should have data in all rows?. I cannot add a new column for this. tried ordering on 'slno' column, but still the same result.

Comment: @faheemKurikkal please edit your comment there are many mistakes, therefor I can't understand, try to use Google Translator

Comment: @BenAyoub your solution is working when my 'id' column has values in all rows. But my problem is, like in my example code, there will some rows which doesn't have 'id' value in it. So I cannot use 'id' to order the table. Is there any other method? Just want to populate the table as in the array dataset.